# How can i insert a multiple listed variable in a while loop?

Tags: python

```
size = (raw_input ('\nWhat Size do you want?').lower()

l_size =['large' , 'lerge' , 'l', 'larg' ,'lorge' ,] 
m_size =['m' , 'med' , 'medium']
s_size =['s' , 'small' , 'smell', 'smoll']
```

I'm using this in order to get the correct input, if the user types incorrectly

```
while size not in ('l_size', 'm_size','s_size'): 
        print ("\033[1;31m Invalid input! Trying Again\n"),
        size = raw_input("\033[1;32;40m What Size do you want? \n")
```

If the user types incorrectly I want to run the program from the start

```
if size in l_size:
    print '\nYour coffee is Large! '
elif size in m_size:
    print '\n Your Coffee is Medium'
elif size in s_size:
    print '\nYour Coffee is Small'
else:
    print '\nIncorrect Typing! Type Properly'\
```

Comment: This is incomprehensible. Please edit your question and add context after reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I suggest you check your code in python editor before posting, like:
https://www.jdoodle.com/python-programming-online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want list concatenation:

```
while size not in l_size + m_size + s_size:
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra parentheses around `raw_input()`.

```
size = raw_input('\nWhat Size do you want?').lower()

l_size = ['large', 'lerge', 'l', 'larg','lorge'] 
m_size = ['m', 'med', 'medium']
s_size = ['s', 'small', 'smell', 'smoll']
```

While `size` is not in those lists, you need to reset the `size`, not create the new variable `num`. Like @iBug said, you need concatenation of the lists to loop through.

```
while size not in l_size + m_size + s_size:
    print("\033[1;31m Invalid input! Trying Again\n")
    size = raw_input("\033[1;32;40m What Size do you want? \n")
```

Comment: Also, you are trying to use the variable names of the lists as strings. This does not do what you think it does :)

Comment: So what do i need to do?How can I represent the names of the lists instead of using that as strings?

Comment: Use them as they are. For example, `size in l_size`, not `size in "l_size"`.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you! again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
size = raw_input("\033[1;32;40m What Size do you want? \n").lower()
l_size = ['large', 'lerge', 'l', 'larg','lorge']
m_size = ['m', 'med', 'medium']
s_size = ['s', 'small', 'smell', 'smoll']

while size not in l_size + m_size + s_size:
       print ("\033[1;31m Invalid input! Trying Again\n"),
       size = raw_input("\033[1;32;40m What Size do you want? \n").lower()
       l_size = ['large', 'lerge', 'l', 'larg','lorge']
       m_size = ['m', 'med', 'medium']
       s_size = ['s', 'small', 'smell', 'smoll']


if size in l_size:
    print '\n Your coffee is Large! '
elif size in m_size:
    print '\n Your Coffee is Medium'
elif size in s_size:
    print '\n Your Coffee is Small'
else:
    print '\n Incorrect Typing! Type Properly'\
```